# Копирование файлов по маске в путях

Tags: windows, cmd, totalcommander

В общем, есть некоторый путь.

Я знаю некоторое начало пути и конец пути, однако, не знаю как будут называться некоторые папки.

Например:

> C:\Folder1\Folder2\*\*\file.txt

Как видите, я знаю некоторый начальный путь, знаю определенное кол-во уровней, но как эти папки будут называться я не знаю, так же знаю конечное имя файла.

Есть ли какая-нибудь консольная утилита в Windows, которая по такой маске нашла и скопировала бы мне файл?

Вроде, из того, что я смог найти они копируют только по маске самого файла.

Или может быть в Total Commander есть такой функционал?

Comment: Конечно есть. **FORFILES /S /P "C:\Folder1\Folder2" /M file.txt /c "cmd /c copy @file c:\ResultDir"** Примечание: **WinXP** и **W2K WKS** не содержат данной утилиты в комплекте, для них можно взять с **W2K3 Srv**

Comment: Обсуждение богатства функционала  **Total Commander** займет не одну статью.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через Total Commander. Заходим в каталог "C:\Folder1\Folder2". Затем нажимаем кнопку "Показать все файлы без каталогов". Сортируем по имени и копируем нужные файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если файлов миллион, то тотал умрет или будет их долго отображать.